# stochastic interest rate $r_t=x_t+y_t$

Tags: interest-rates, stochastic-calculus

Let
$$dr_t=(\alpha(t)-\beta r_t)dt+\sigma   dW_t$$
where $\alpha$ is non stochastic process and $\beta$ and $\sigma$ are constant.
Can we write process $r_t$ in the form
$$r_t=x_t+y_t$$
where the process $x_t$ satisfies
$$dx_t=-\beta x_t dt+\sigma dW_t$$
and $y_t$ be a deterministic function. I used Ito's lemma but was not useful.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the usual integrating factor method,
\begin{align*}
r_t = r_0e^{-\beta t} + \int_0^t \alpha(s) e^{-\beta(t-s)}ds +\sigma \int_0^t e^{-\beta(t-s)}dW_s.
\end{align*}
Let
\begin{align*}
x_t &=\sigma \int_0^t e^{-\beta(t-s)}dW_s, \textrm { and}\\ 
y_t &=r_0e^{-\beta t} + \int_0^t \alpha(s) e^{-\beta(t-s)}ds.
\end{align*}
Then $r_t = x_t + y_t$, moreover,
\begin{align*}
dx_t &= d\left(\sigma e^{-\beta t} \int_0^t e^{\beta s}dW_s \right)\\
&=-\beta \left(\sigma e^{-\beta t} \int_0^t e^{\beta s}dW_s\right)dt + \sigma dW_t\\
&=-\beta x_t dt + \sigma dW_t,
\end{align*}
and $y_t$ is a deterministic function.

Comment: Thank you but $dx_t=-\beta x_t dt +\sigma dW_t$